# Advanced Python scraper - pagnations

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping

Im trying to help a friend write a scraper that collects links from a site, however the items are stored in a model, and i cannot get my code to load the next page of the model..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

# Connect to a database (creates the database file if it doesn't exist)
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/jacqu/Desktop/Github - Jacques/RenBoss Data Scraper/DB.db')

# Create a table
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urls (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, url TEXT)")

# Create a session object
session = requests.Session()

# Make an HTTP request to the URL and get the response
url = "https://jlrequipment.service-solutions.com/en-US/Pages/ItemListing.aspx?catID=321490"

# Set the page size to the maximum value
data = {
    "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ItemListDisplayControl2$lvTools$ddlItemsPerPageTop": "100"
}
response = session.post(url, data=data)

def scrape_page(soup):
    elements = soup.find_all(id="hlinkItemID", class_="ProductNumber")
    for element in elements:
        href = element.get("href")
        print("Link: " + href)
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES (?)", (href,))

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    scrape_page(soup)

    next_page = True
    while next_page:
        pager = soup.find("div", class_="ms-pager")

        if pager is not None:
            next_link = pager.find("a", title="Next")

            if next_link is not None:
                viewstate = soup.find("input", {"id": "__VIEWSTATE"}).get("value")
                viewstategenerator = soup.find("input", {"id": "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"}).get("value")
                eventvalidation = soup.find("input", {"id": "__EVENTVALIDATION"}).get("value")
                eventtarget = next_link.get("href").split("'")[1]

                data = {
                    "__EVENTTARGET": eventtarget,
                    "__VIEWSTATE": viewstate,
                    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": viewstategenerator,
                    "__EVENTVALIDATION": eventvalidation
                }
                response = session.post(url, data=data)

                if response.status_code == 200:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
                    scrape_page(soup)
            else:
                next_page = False
        else:
            print("Pagination not found. Skipping further pages.")
            next_page = False

conn.commit()
```

if you follow the link you will see the model im trying to scrape and the controller im trying to call

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ItemListDisplayControl2$lvTools$DataPager1$ctl03$ctl00','')"><b>&nbsp;&gt;</b></a>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gonna have to do a few things to make it work, first import `requests` at the begining of your script `import requests` then use the correct class name for the elements containing the product numbers replace`elements = soup.find_all(id="hlinkItemID", class_="ProductNumber")` by `elements = soup.find_all(class_="ItemNumber")` then modify your loop to extract the correct `href`

```
for element in elements:
    href = element.find("a").get("href")
    print("Link: " + href)
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO urls (url) VALUES (?)", (href,))
```

Comment: hey thanks for this but it still only scrapes the first 10 items, i see I forgot to add requests in the code I posted here